SAS - Modifying key-value pairs in a macro variable
I have a macro variable with key-value pairs, separated by a space. Sometimes, a value itself can consist of key-value pairs, but now separated with a semi-colon (and one semi-colon at the end) and enclosed by double quotes. Single values are sometimes enclosed by double quotes and sometimes not. I would like to be able to adjust the contents of this macro variable in a structured and flexible way.
My macro variable has the following structure:
%LET connection_string = KEY1=value1 KEY2="Value2" KEY3="KEY3A=VALUE3A;KEY3B=VALUE3B;KEY3C=VALUE WITH SPACES3C;" KEY4="KEY4A=VALUE4A;KEY4B=VALUE4B;";

I would like to be able to add, delete or update key-value pairs. The exact number of (sub-)key-value pairs that exist in the connection_string is not known beforehand.
The modifications should be condition-based, e.g.:

update if exist, otherwise add
delete if exist

The key-value pairs that I need to modify differ per project, but suppose that I need to add/delete/update the following key-value pairs:

KEY3B=NEW_VALUE3B (update in KEY3)
KEY3D=VALUE3D (add in KEY3)
KEY4B=VALUE4B (delete in KEY4)
KEY5="VALUE5" (add as KEY5)

My idea would be to:

decompose the string in the macro variable into a dataset
decompose any key-value pairs into another dataset, if the value of that pair has at least 1 semi-colon
modify the datasets according to the changes that need to be made
roll-up the datasets and compose the connection_string and store this in a new macro variable connection_string_upd

But perhaps there is a better way as well.
Dataset based on original macro variable:
| key  | value
__________________________________________________________________
| KEY1 | value1
| KEY2 | "Value2"
| KEY3 | "KEY3A=VALUE3A;KEY3B=VALUE3B;KEY3C=VALUE WITH SPACES3C;"
| KEY4 | "KEY4A=VALUES4A;KEY4B=VALUE4B;"

Dataset with modifications
| key  | value
___________________________________________________________________________________
| KEY1 | value1
| KEY2 | "Value2"
| KEY3 | "KEY3A=VALUE3A;KEY3B=NEW_VALUE3B;KEY3C=VALUE WITH SPACES3C;KEY3D=VALUE3D;"
| KEY4 | "KEY4A=VALUE4A;"
| KEY5 | "VALUE5"

The result should be:
%PUT &connection_string_upd.;
KEY1=value1 KEY2="Value2" KEY3="KEY3A=VALUE3A;KEY3B=NEW_VALUE3B;KEY3C=VALUE WITH SPACES3C;KEY3D=VALUE3D;" KEY4="KEY4A=VALUE4A;" KEY5="VALUE5";

How would I best approach this?
It feels like this problem of decomposing/composing seems mostly suited for data steps. I tried to have a go, but these double quotes are making my life hard. Code snippets below didn't get my where I want to go. Hopefully, someone can help.
DATA test;
    INPUT input_text : $1024.;
    INFILE DATALINES DSD;
    input_text_resolved = DEQUOTE(RESOLVE(QUOTE(input_text)));
    PUT input_text_resolved;
    DATALINES;
&connection_string.
    ;
RUN;

/* this gives a lot of errors */
DATA test2;
    /* try to double the double quotes (to escape them) */
    DO i=1 TO COUNTW(COMPRESS("&connection_string.", '"', '""'));
        item = SCAN(COMPRESS("&connection_string.", '"'), i, ' ');
        OUTPUT;
    END;
RUN;


This sounds like a tough problem.  What are the source data that are giving you this list of key-value pairs, with nested key-value pairs within some values?  It's like a python dictionary or something?  I think I would avoid using the macro language at all, would instead try to do this as data manipulations.

What exactly is that middle step "modify the datasets according to the changes that need to be made"?  That probably has a big impact on what methods will work.

To get the value of a macro variable into a dataset variable use SYMGET() function.  Remember that macro variables can hold 64k bytes and dataset variables only 32k bytes.

Why does the value of KEY2 in your example have quotes around it but the value for KEY1 does not.  Are those quotes significant?  What if a value just happened to have a semicolon in it?  How can you distinguish that from a nested key/value list?

How are the desired changes structured? In a data set?

The connection_string is used to connect to a database system. This is a standard string that our IT organisation has defined to use. I need to be able to tune the settings for specific projects. I don't want to deviate from the format, so the quotes are significant.
The desired changes can be structured in a data set,  or in another way. But preferably I would like to keep it in a separate step, so that it is not 'hidden' in the code in some other steps.

It's clunky but this parses connection string and updates.  You should be able to adapt parse the update string.
%LET connection_string = KEY1=value1 KEY2="Value2" KEY3="KEY3A=VALUE3A;KEY3B=VALUE3B;KEY3C=VALUE WITH SPACES3C;" KEY4="KEY4A=VALUE4A;KEY4B=VALUE4B;";
data test master(keep=id sid value);
   string = symget('connection_string');
   length pair pair2 $128 id sid $32 value1-value2 $128;
   do i = 1 to countw(string,,'qs');
      pair = scan(string,i,,'sq');
      put pair =;
      p = indexc(pair,'=');
      id = substr(pair,1,p-1);
      value1 = substr(pair,p+1); 
      if indexc(value1,'=') then do;
         value1 = dequote(value1);
         do j = 1 to countw(value1,';');
            pair2 = scan(value1,j,';');
            if not missing(pair2) then do;
               p2 = indexc(pair2,'=');
               sid = substr(pair2,1,p2-1);
               value2 = substr(pair2,p2+1);
               value = value2;
               output;
               end;
            end;
         end;
      else do;
         value = value1;
         output;
         end;
      end; 
   run;
proc print;
   run;

data trans;
   length id sid $32 value $64;
   input id sid value &;
   cards4;
KEY3 KEY3B NEW_VALUE3B (update in KEY3)
KEY3 KEY3D VALUE3D (add in KEY3)
KEY4 KEY4B _
KEY5 . "VALUE5" (add as KEY5)
;;;;
   run;
proc print;
   run;

data updates;
   update master trans;
   by id sid;
   run;
proc print;
   run;



If you wanted KEY4/KEY4B to disappear then you might want to only output observations with non missing VALUE.  if last.sid and missing(value) then delete;

Nice. Thanks for this! It is a bit clunky, but it does the job fairly neat.

Looks like there are two keys. Parse your STRINGS appropriately and I believe the rest is standard SAS UPDATE statement.
data master;
   length id sid $32 value $64;
   input id sid value &;
   cards4;
KEY1 . value1
KEY2 . "Value2"
KEY3 KEY3A VALUE3A
KEY3 KEY3B VALUE3B
KEY3 KEY3C VALUE WITH SPACES3C
KEY4 KEY4A VALUE4A
KEY4 KEY4B VALUE4B
;;;;   
   run;
proc print;   
   run;

data trans;
   length id sid $32 value $64;
   input id sid value &;
   cards4;
KEY3 KEY3B NEW_VALUE3B (update in KEY3)
KEY3 KEY3D VALUE3D (add in KEY3)
KEY4 KEY4B VALUE4B (delete in KEY4)
KEY5 . "VALUE5" (add as KEY5)
;;;;
   run;
proc print;
   run;

data updates;
   update master trans;
   by id sid;
   run;
proc print;
   run;



I did not handle the DELETE (in KEY4) properly how is that communicated in the transaction string?

Good observation that there are two keys. Hadn't thought of it like that. My initial thinking is that I would like to have it fully dynamic for any number of keys. But I think we can assume that there are maximum two levels of keys, so this is a nice way to do it.
